# Recursion - Understanding return

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Return
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Factorial(10));
            Console.WriteLine(test());
        }

        private static int Factorial(int factorialNum)
        {
            if (factorialNum <= 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return factorialNum * Factorial(factorialNum - 1);
        }

        public static int test()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Okay so here is my thought proccess. If i make a method, that returns 1. I.e: `public static int test() { return 1; }` And Console.WriteLine that method, then it will say 1. If I change it to 3 it will write 3, and so on. So with the other method, I'm saying that I want to * it with the factorialNum -1. And return that. But if it is 1 it should return 1. And no matter which int I put inside it, it will always eventually = 1. Because we are saying factorialNum -1 But why is it that, when it is eventually 1. And it returns 1 Then why isn't the output in the Console.WriteLine 1 Since we're returning 1

Comment: Your thought process and confusion isn't clear. What *are* you getting, and exactly *why* don't you think you should be getting it? Examples help :)

Comment: You call `Factorial(10)` so why do you expect that to return `1`? Instead it returns `10 * Factorial(9)` as `10` is not less than or equal to `1` (`if (factorialNum <= 1)`. From the POV of your `main` method, the recursion doesn't matter - imagine replacing `Factorial(9)` with a number, say `362880`.

Comment: Try debugging Factorial method with passing 1  and 2 to it. That will help to understand how it works

Comment: Okay so here is my thought proccess. If i make a method, that returns 1. I.e:

```
        public static int test()
        {
            return 1;
        }
```

And Console.WriteLine that method, then it will say 1. If I change it to 3 it will write 3, and so on. So with the other method, I'm saying that I want to * it with the factorialNum -1. And return that. But if it is 1 it should return 1. And no matter which int I put inside it, it will always eventually = 1. Because we are saying factorialNum -1 But why is it that, when it is eventually 1. And it returns 1

Comment: Then why isn't the output in the Console.WriteLine 1
Since we're returning 1

Comment: It does return one - eventually. But then what happens? It's recursion, try to reason it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to execute the code of calling:

```
Factorial(4)
```

When this method is called for 4 the return statement would be

```
4 * Factorial(3)
```

So we have to call Factorial(3) now and we would get

```
3 * Factorial(2)
```

Last

```
2 * Factorial(1)
```

At the last point Factorial(1) would return 1 and the result:

```
2 * 1
```

Would be passed to 3 * Factorial(2) and would be become

```
3 * 2 * 1
```

And that would be passed at the end to 4 * Factorial(3):

```
4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

and now the method returns 24, which is the factorial of 4.

You have to keep an eye on the call stack. The fact that it would stop the recursive calls of the method at the base case `factorialNum <= 1`, it doesn't mean that the result of calling that method with any argument would be 1.

On the other hand, when you call test you don't have recursive calls, you return immediately 1.

Comment: Okay. So the 

```
return factorialNum * Factorial(factorialNum - 1);
```

Keeps "adding" to itself. I tried changing the return 1 to 2. And it multiplied the result with 2. So I guess that it just says. "Hey when we have multiplied with everything, we want to multiply it with 1" Is that understood correctly?

Comment: @SonnyChaudhry I am sorry, but I don't get your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
return factorialNum * Factorial(factorialNum - 1);
```

In the above `factorialNum` will always be 10 since that was the input value, and will return `10*Factorial(9)`.
Then in the next loop it will be `9*Factorial(8)` and so on. So the final return value will be `10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1`

Answer (score 1):

You get the number 3628800 when you run the Factorial(10) because 10! equals 3628800. If you run through the code, Factorial() returns the current number * the current number - 1. So it returns 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 3628800.

You are in fact returning 1 at the end of Factorial(10), but this 1 is simply multiplied by the numbers that come prior.

To get the console to return a 1, you would have to run Factorial(1) because 1! = 1.